# Simulating nested selectors without nesting them to combine with simple selectors

Tags: sass, css-selectors

Say I have this:

```
$my-font-size:14px;

p{
    font-size:$my-font-size;
}
div.section{
    &.type-1,&.type-2{
        h1{
            font-size:$my-font-size;
        }
    }
}
```

Now say I want to combine this into one line. So I write:

```
p,div.section.type-1 h1, div.section.type-2 h1{$font-size:$my-font-size;}
```

But say I still want to benefit from the functionality that I don't have to repeat the "parent" which is `div`. Is there any way to do this? Like for example:

```
p,div.section((&.type-1,&.type-2)) h1{$font-size:$my-font-size;}
```

So basically I'm looking for some sort of shorthand syntax so that I can combine it with another selector.

```
div.section{
    &.type-1,&.type-2{
        h1{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sass 3.3 or later

The function you're looking for is called `selector-append`.  In your case, however, you also need to combine it with `selector-nest` for the h1.

```
p, #{selector-nest(selector-append('div.section', ('.type-1', '.type-2')), h1)} {font-size:$my-font-size;}
```

## Sass 3.2 or older

For older Sass versions, you can use the `append-selector` function that comes with Compass, but both arguments must be strings.  As above, you'll need to combine it with the `nest` function for the h1.

```
p, #{nest(append-selector('div.section', '.type-1, .type-2'), h1)} {font-size:$my-font-size;}
```

Comment: _is called `selector-append`_ or `append-selector` as later is used in code.

Comment: @Tushar Fixed the typo

Comment: I appreciate this answer. I will accept it if this ends up being the best solution. I'm looking for something more engrained in the language if possible. Using strings and functions becomes extremely messy for something that should be built in.

Comment: The selector-append and selector-nest functions *are* built into the language.  This is the only way to do what you're asking for *without* using nesting.

Comment: With CSS I'm forced to write: `p, div.section.type-1 h1, div.section.type-2 h1`. With Sass I have two options: nest, which I want to avoid because it takes away my abilty to group the selectors with a comma (which to me means that they have the same style for the same reason --- something I want to preserve with the style of my code), or use `append-selector` function which makes it look like a script and not a selector. I wish there was a way to write that selector more succinctly. Like: `p, div.section[.type1,.type2] h1`. What is between `[]` would be "or". –